# What's freezing my cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Quick question. How come whenever I use Berkshelf to manage my cookbook dependencies, my own cookbooks get frozen? Is there a way to unfreeze it?

```
knife cookbook upload myNodeApp

Uploading myNodeApp  [0.1.0]
ERROR: Version 0.1.0 of cookbook myNodeApp is frozen. Use --force to override.
WARNING: Not updating version constraints for LighthouseApi in the environment as the cookbook is frozen.
ERROR: Failed to upload 1 cookbook.
```

**update:**

here's my Berksfile.

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

metadata

cookbook 'apt', '~> 2.4.0'
cookbook 'nginx', '~> 2.7.4'
cookbook 'redisio', '~> 1.7.1'
cookbook 'mysql', '~> 5.3.6'
cookbook 'nodejs', '~> 1.3.0'
cookbook 'npm', '~> 0.1.2'
cookbook 'mongodb', '~> 0.16.1'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Berkshelf automatically freezes cookbooks on upload. You can disable this using the `--no-freeze` option.

```
$ berks help upload
Usage:
  berks upload [COOKBOOKS]

Options:
  -b, [--berksfile=PATH]                               # Path to a Berksfile to operate off of.
  -e, [--except=one two three]                         # Exclude cookbooks that are in these groups.
  -o, [--only=one two three]                           # Only cookbooks that are in these groups.
      [--no-freeze], [--no-no-freeze]                  # Do not freeze uploaded cookbook(s).
      [--force]                                        # Upload all cookbook(s) even if a frozen one exists on the Chef Server.
      [--ssl-verify], [--no-ssl-verify]                # Disable/Enable SSL verification when uploading cookbooks.
  -s, [--skip-syntax-check], [--no-skip-syntax-check]  # Skip Ruby syntax check when uploading cookbooks.
      [--halt-on-frozen], [--no-halt-on-frozen]        # Exit with a non zero exit code if the Chef Server already has the version of the cookbook(s).
  -c, [--config=PATH]                                  # Path to Berkshelf configuration to use.
  -F, [--format=FORMAT]                                # Output format to use.
                                                       # Default: human
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]                          # Silence all informational output.
  -d, [--debug], [--no-debug]                          # Output debug information
```

Comment: is including "metadata" in my Berksfile causing it to freeze my cookbook?

Comment: sorry, dumb question. so if i'm using Berkshelf, i should not use `knife cookbook upload` right?

Comment: You should not use `knife` to upload cookbooks if you are using Berkshelf.